# Why does my page default to Views/Home/Index and fail to show page in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, view

For some reason, my ASP.NET application defaults to the following:

Views/Home/Index and shows an 404 error, why does it keep doing this?

I did not modify any pages, though I added some views.

[image]

Comment: You can't load a view file directly; you need to request an action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Visual Studio**, it sometimes happens to me too. When I added a view and my focus is on a .cshtml view file, starting debug opens the current view file directly as it opens in the aspx page for webforms.

This may be a bug (or a feature for webforms project) that it opens the current page under focus. You can simply remove the .cshtml (in MVC projects) portion from the URL (in browser window) and it will be all good.

I hope it will help someone.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Not sure, why it does that, I did not modify the routing or anything, just VS seems to what to use the default with cshtml on it with the Views folder.

Answer (score 3):

You need to access controller, not View. Instead of /views/home/index.cshtml you need to access /Home/